# SyntaxError: Unexpected token - when importing external class - Protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am importing an external class into my protractor test. But when running the test. I get a syntax error on Import. I believe im importing and exporting the class correctly. And i only get the error at run time. I am using gulp to compile typescript.

The test was working when I had the class in the same project, but now im using it from an external project, and importing into the test.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
import { Helper } from './src/helper';
   ^
```

**Main-Project**

```
test.ts
import { Helper, People, Groups } from 'sub-project';

describe('Test Description', () => {


 let helper: Helper;
 let people: People;
 let groups: Groups;


before(async () => {
    helper = new Helper();
    people = new People();
    groups = new Groups();

});
```

**SUb-Project**

```
export class Helper {

    private httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public async myFunction): {

    }
}
```

app.ts

```
import { Helper } from './src/helper';
import { People } from './src/people';
import { Groups } from './src/groups';

export { Helper, People, Groups };
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": [
            "chai",
            "chai-as-promised",
            "mocha"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring some other file for importing.

To export a class in TS do the following.

```
//    index2.ts

export class user {

    display(name) {

        return `Welcome ${name}`;

    }

}
```

To import a class from a specific file .

```
 //core2.ts

import { user } from './index2'

const a = new user();

console.log(a.display(`Bharath`));
```

refer https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Your IDE will pop what can be imported from the file your specified. Hit ctrl - space to see the recommendations.

[image]

Comment: I have tried importing with path to class name, and also from package name
import `{ Helper } from 'sub-project/src/helper` and  `{ Helper } from 'sub-project'`

Comment: Before importing Helper just specify the file location and inside flower braces just hit ctrl space.Is your IDE popping Hepler?

Comment: yes, the right class name populates in the arrows. But i still get the runtime error.

Comment: Have you compiled your TS to JS?.

Comment: I run tsc before running the test

Comment: Make sure you are not referring TS file for execution. You should be mentioning the compiled JS file

Comment: im running the test the same way, i did when the class existing in the same project, the only difference now, is that im using the class externally. So shouldnt the way i run the test be the same?

Comment: and im using gulp to compile typescript